# Pandas options not working within a class

Tags: python

I am having some difficulty with the interaction within a class and was hoping someone could point out my mistake.  What I am trying to do, is to load a file into Pandas, and then to set the pandas options to display the entire file.  Simple!  But I am making a mess of the scope and was hoping someone could help.

```
class Reviewer:
    def __init__(self, review_file):
        self.review_file = review_file
        self.data = pd.read_csv(review_file)

        self.set_pandas_display_options()
        print(self.data)

    def set_pandas_display_options() -> None:
        display = pd.options.display
        display.max_columns = 100
        display.max_rows = 1000
        display.max_colwidth = 199
        display.width = None
```

But unfortunately what I get is the usual truncated pandas output

```
2          Neg   info0
3          Neg   info1
4          Neg   info2
...        ...                                                                                                                                                                                                     ...
1377       Pos   info 1377
1378       Pos   info 1378
```

Comment: As per official docs, you should use a setter method for the specific property you want to change, for example: `pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 1000)` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

Comment: Try passing `self` inside `def set_pandas_display_options()`

Answer (score 1):

So thanks very much pavel.  I corrected:

```
    def set_pandas_display_options(self) -> None:
        pd.options.display.max_columns = 100
        pd.options.display.max_rows = 2000
        pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 199
        pd.options.display.width = None
```